# normality test for all levels of variable in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I want to test the normality for each group or level of a continuous variable before doing an ANOVA. Specifically, it's age vs different religious preferences. The dummies page (http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-test-data-normality-in-a-formal-way-in-r.html) mentions a way to do it with shapiro and tapply, but I think there's an error in the code. Anybody know if this should work?

Comment: Don't know if there are errors in their code, but for sure there are errors (big errors!) in their logic. The sentence: `This p-value tells you what the chances are that the sample comes from a normal distribution` is so false that I suggest you to stop reading there. See this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misunderstandings_of_p-values to understand why p-values are not what they are saying.

Comment: @JuanTamad Hi, if any answer solves your problem can you click on "accept it" so that other people can see it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are mentionning a tutorial page where a shapiro.test is done across a grouping variable. THe code does have a little error:

```
with(beaver, tapply(temp, activ, shapiro.test)
```

it should be:

```
with(beaver2, tapply(temp, activ, shapiro.test))
```

If your data exceeds 5000 observations, you can take a random sample of it, but I couldn't say if it is statistically valid:

```
with(beaver2, tapply(temp, activ, function(x) shapiro.test(sample(x, min(NROW(x), 5000)))))
```

I suggest checking the Cross-Validated site to get an answer on that subject, for instance [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/146765/66519)

However,

Concerning the remark of Nicola mentionning the erroneous interpretation of a normality p-value, i completely agree. Let's take an example, let's create a distribution that only returns these three values: 1, 2, and 3 with 1/3 probability each. It's nothing like a normal distribution.
However, a shapiro.test indicates a p-value of 1 for this data:

```
shapiro.test(c(2,3,1))
#### Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#### data:  c(1, 2, 3)
#### W = 1, p-value = 1
```

Comment: Yes, I know about the p value definition.. But I can't make the code to work still. I'm using my own, so the error in beaver didn't matter, and I noticed the missing closing ). But I still get "Error: unexpected ')' in "tapply(gss$relig, gss$age, shapiro.test))". Is this supposed to be preceded by something I'm missing? In ?with it states: with is a generic function that evaluates expr in a local environment constructed from data. ... - I think my data (dataframe gss) is in the environment.

Comment: In the textbook "OpenIntroStats" 3rd edition, p253,  shows normal probability plots for each level of a grouping variable. Wonder if there's a way to this in R?

Comment: Nevermind that first comment. I had left off something. I still get " : sample size must be between 3 and 5000" for shapiro. My data is 57061. Is there any other way?

Comment: Here's how you get the normal probability plots, with ggplot2: ggplot(gss, aes(sample = age)) + stat_qq() + facet_wrap(~ relig) + xlab("Theoretical Quantiles") + ylab("Sample Quantiles") + ggtitle("Normal Probability Plots")#qqplots by group